# Instagram-API with python

Tags: python, api, instagram, instagram-api

I recently started using the instagram-API in python. I built successfully some programs, and then I searched a way to create an Instagram account through the api - but I couldn't find.
Is there a way to create an instargram account from the api (python), and then send the login details (user,pass) and the token, secret token to the user?
Thanks, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/) and you'll quickly discern that their API isn't designed to allow for third-party, programmatic user account creation.

The only way to create an account with Instagram is by downloading their iOS or Android app and following the account creation process that way.

From an end user perspective, what would be the use case for granting a third party application all the sensitive personal data required to create an Instagram account? Because an end user can only upload media to their account via the app, why wouldn't someone just want to sign up when they download the app?

Comment: So I can only upload/download data from/to instagram?

Comment: @Mk you can only upload media via the app, data you can grab via the API. Check the documentation [here](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/), bottom of the page.